# What is the best way for me to gather my simulation results?

Tags: python, dataframe, simulation

I have a simulation model that returns a dataframe with information about the charging behavior of an agent:

```
   Station  kWh   Timestamp
   a        5     2020-01-01 09:22:07
   b        10    2020-08-20 12:02:10
   c        15    2020-12-10 17:31:39
```

I then have a function that takes as an input n (number of agents) and writes the dataframe for each agent in a csv file.

What I'm stuck at is how to run the simulation, lets say 1000 times, for 1000 agents. That would give me 1 million dataframes and I need to be able to gather results from each simulation so I can't write it in the same csv file.
Can anyone recommend a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code which may help you. It would be easier to answer with a reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def agent_sim(name):
    # do stuff ...
    # create agent name column
    df['agent'] = name
    # create timestamp for simulation time
    df['sim_timestamp'] = dt.datetime.now()
    return df

# create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

agents = ['agent a', 'agent b', ...]

for agent in agents:
    for i in range(1000):
        df = df.append(agent_sim(agent))

# write simultations to csv
df.to_csv('agent_simulations.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what your requirements are.

Here are some possibilities (I can provide basic code if needed):

#### Write one csv file per dataframe

Although I'm assuming you do not want to do that based on the wording of your question, it is still a possibility.

#### Use yaml/json

Using `pandas.DataFrame`'s [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method you could store all your data in a single json file.

You would need to find a unique identifier for each simulation to index the data.

#### Use a database

Have you considered using something like [tinydb](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb)? It is a lightweight NoSQL database.